# Joomla cannot install component, inspite of giving 777 permissions to all folders and safe_mode=Off

Tags: php, installation, joomla

I am having a issue that is becoming a pain in *** for me.  I have been trying to install the components into the joomla, but joomla installer is giving me the following error.

```
JFolder::create: Could not create directory
Unable to create destination
```

I have disabled the safe_mode on the server (linux, cent os 5)
Also give permission 777 to all the files and folders.
i have even tried using the ftp layer enabled and getting error:(JFTP: bad response)

Does anybody have any idea that how this joomla installer works.
Kindly please, help me out of this.

Thanks
SIA

Comment: If you are getting a bad response, then the FTP is not connecting. What does the page say on Help > System Info > Directory Permissions?

Comment: yes, All directories are "Writable". i have given 777 to all directories,sub-directories and files. But still unable to create the destination.

Comment: are your tmp and log folders correct?

Comment: Is your ftp settings correct in the admin?

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be the `owner` of the directories (not the permissions). Try to run the following from Joomla `root` folder (usually `/var/www/html`):

```
chown -R apache:apache *
```

and then try to re-install.